# How to delete every 0.2-th row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

```
df_o = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'])
```

I would like to continuously delete 4 consecutive rows but always spare the fifth in the dataframe above. The final result should be:

```
df_o = pd.DataFrame(['e', 'j', 'o'])
```

My idea `df_o = df_o.drop(df_o.iloc[::0.2].index)`does not work. It works well for deleting every n-th row if n is an integer, but not for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_o.groupby(np.arange(len(df_o.index))//5).last()
```

Output:

```
   0
0  e
1  j
2  o
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `loc`:

```
import numpy as np
out = df_o.loc[np.arange(1, len(df_o)+1)%5==0, 0].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['e', 'j', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: slice!

```
df_o.iloc[4::5]
```

Generalization:

```
N = 5
df_o.iloc[N-1::N]
```

Output:

```
    0
4   e
9   j
14  o
```